# Could not delete any project in an on premise Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

According to [Microsoft's document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/delete-project?view=azure-devops), a project could be deleted from the Overview menu of Project settings. but in my own on premise Azure Devops 2019, there is no Delete button at all.
Does anyone know any solution?

screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are not a member of the **Project Administrators** group, the Delete project column will not be displayed.

If you want to have permission to delete the project, you need to be added to the Project Administrators group in project settings or Project Collection Administrators group in organization settings.

[image]

You can also delete the project in the Projects of organization settings，see if this is feasible.
[image]

Comment: I have been the only member of Project Administrator already. still no Delete button is displayed!

Comment: Glad to help you : )